# create new column on conditions python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a ref table `df_ref` like this:

```
col1 col2 ref
a    b    a,b
c    d    c,d
```

I need to create a new column in another table based on ref table.The table like this:

```
col1 col2 
a    b   
a    NULL 
NULL b 
a    NULL 
a    NULL 
c    d  
c    NULL 
NULL NULL
```

The output table `df_org` looks like:

```
col1  col2   ref
a     b      a,b
a     NULL   a,b
NULL  b      a,b
a     NULL   a,b
a     NULL   a,b
c     d      c,d
c     NULL   c,d
NULL  NULL   NULL
```

If any column value in `col1` and `col2` can find in ref table, it will use the ref col in ref table. If `col1` and `col2` are `NULL`, So they cannot find anything in ref table, just return `NULL`. I use this code, but it doesn't work.

```
df_org['ref']=np.where(((df_org['col1'].isin(df_ref['ref'])) | 
         (df_org['col2'].isin(df_ref['ref']))  
          ), df_ref['ref'], 'NULL')
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Comment: Your in format input/output is unclear. Please provide DataFrame constructors

Comment: the logic is :based on reference table, if column 1 or column 2 has value that can be found in reference table, so we give new-col a ref value. For example, col1=a,col2=b,so ref=a,b. If col1 is a ,but col2 is null,a can be found in (a,b).so 2nd row is a,b. If col1 is null, col2 is null,we can not find any value in reference table.So ref col is NULL.

Comment: If col1 =c, col2=d,they are in new combination (c,d).If col1=c, col2=null,ref col should still (c,d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to perform two merges and combine them:

```
df_org = (
 df.merge(df_ref.drop('col2', axis=1), on='col1', how='left')
   .combine_first(df.merge(df_ref.drop('col1', axis=1), on='col2', how='left'))
)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2  ref
0    a    b  a,b
1    a  NaN  a,b
2  NaN    b  a,b
3    a  NaN  a,b
4    a  NaN  a,b
5    c    d  c,d
6    c  NaN  c,d
7  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( df.merge(df_ref[['col1', 'ref']], how="left", on='col1' )       # add column for col1 refs
    .merge(df_ref[['col2', 'ref']], how="left", on='col2',        # add column for col2 refs
                                    suffixes=('_col1', '_col2'))  # set suffixes to both ref columns
    .assign(ref=lambda x: x['ref_col1'].fillna(x['ref_col2']))    # add column from 'ref_col1' and fill 'NaN' from 'ref_col2' 
    .drop(['ref_col1', 'ref_col2'], axis=1)                       # drop 'ref_col1' and 'ref_col2' columns
)
```

results in

```
  col1 col2  ref
0    a    b  a,b
1  NaN    b  a,b
2    a  NaN  a,b
3    a  NaN  a,b
4    a  NaN  a,b
5  NaN  NaN  NaN
6    c  NaN  c,d
7    c    d  c,d
```

Comment: when i run your code, there is an error: KeyError: 'ref_col1' @hpchavaz

Comment: @Rye, works perfectly here. I updated a bit simplifying merge  parameters